# Add a custom attribbut to fomregistrationType Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have three php class Ville.php,User.php,Gouvernorat.php and the relationship between them are User have One ville so I have an attribute ville in my class User and the ville belongs to one Gouvernorat so I have an attribute Gouvernorat in my class ville too, So here is my RegistrationFormType:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    // add your custom field
    $builder->add('name');
    //$builder->add('prenom');
    //$builder->add('telephone');
    $builder->add('ville','entity', array(
        'class' => 'Smart\UserBundle\Entity\Ville',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->orderBy('u.nom', 'ASC');
                },
        'property' => 'nom',
        'multiple' => false,
        'required' => true));
    $builder->add('Gouvernorat','entity', array(
        'class' => 'Smart\UserBundle\Entity\Gouvernorat',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                            ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
                },
        'property' => 'name',
        'multiple' => false,
        'required' => true));

}
```

the problem is when I add Gouvernorat to generate my combobox it tell me the class User haven't attribute Gouvernorat :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Neither the property               
Gouvernorat" nor one of the methods "getGouvernorat()", "isGouvernorat()",   
"hasGouvernorat()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class 
 "Smart\UserBundle\Entity\User".") in ::layout.html.twig at line 101.
```

if I add an attribut gouverorat to my class User and maket it getter and setter it works but not practice because only my class ville have the attribute governorat.
How I can resolve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide some information about your entities.

Comment: Please post the contents of Smart\UserBundle\Entity\User in particular.

Comment: Try with 'mapped' => false

Comment: yes freind I tried 'mapped' => false and it works :) Thanx